# Register .ocx file with Powershell

Tags: powershell, ocx

I need to register an ocx file with Powershell. I know how to do it from VBScript and/or command line, but I can't figure out how to accomplish the same thing from Powershell. 
Do I need to call regsvr32.exe, or is there a better, more elegant way to do it?

Answer (score 2):

What regsvr32 basically does is load the ocx and call its DllRegisterServer function. You can do that yourself from PowerShell if you want. [Here](http://limbioliong.wordpress.com/2011/08/11/programmatically-register-com-dlls-in-c/) is an example how to do it from C# and [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mattbie/archive/2010/02/23/how-to-call-net-and-win32-methods-from-powershell-and-your-troubleshooting-packs.aspx) is an example how to load win32 dlls (ocx is a dll) in powershell.

Comment: Are there any examples for loading a dll this way in Powershell? I think I understand the concept, but I can't figure out how to implement it.